# Google Apps Marketplace vs Chrome web store

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

I have a listing in the Google Apps Marketplace (GAM) that used OAuth1.0. My website has now upgraded its google integration parts to OAuth2.0, and I'm trying to reactivate/relist.

My previous understanding of the Chrome Web Store (CWS) was that it was for extensions and what not to the chrome browser, but looking around how to upgrade my listing I keep coming back to the CWS.

Is it correct that the new GAM is basically the CWS but for a website I will be listed under hosted apps? i.e. my website will be listed https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps?_feature=website instead of http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/ ?

Why is the old marketplace link still up then? are apps currently just listed at both places until the old market place just deprecates completely?

Are all the usual features of GAM otherwise the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Marketplace v1 is under deprecation, which is why you cannot publish there. GAM v2 is the Chrome Web Store. Apps on GAM v1 were existing apps prior to the deprecation. If you're upgrading your application, then yes, you will need to migrate over to the Chrome Web Store (GAM v2) and your app will be there rather than the older GAM (v1).

Taken from the [Developer Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/):

> A few apps are still hosted on the deprecated older version of Google
>   Apps Marketplace. The deprecated version documentation remains
>   available to support those apps until the older version reaches its
>   end of life.

Comment: Is there a way to port my reviews for the old app on GAMv1 to the new app on the CWS? I tried the method mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2 but just got a "Not Found" message after doing the PUT. I'm not sure if this is because the upgrade API has reached end of life or it is because I'm still awaiting the GAM review decision of my request for the new app on CWS. If it's end of life...is there now other way to get my old reviews over?

Comment: You need your app published on both v1 and v2. In the link you provided, see the prerequisites. Also, if your PUT fails, you should troubleshoot it by checking the error code, which you can also find on the same page you linked.

Comment: I just spoke to Google and I guess the upgrade API is no longer available: "The migration period for marketplace apps has ended last September. Apps may no longer be migrated nor can reviews. If you migrated your app from the old marketplace before Sept. of 2014, you may still be able to migrate reviews. ".............oh dear.